# Google Apps Script Form textValidationBuilder does not recognize regex pattern

Tags: regex, forms, google-apps-script

I am trying to create a Form with apps script and for some reason it will not allow the simplest phone number validation in a TextItem input field. I only need the user to enter their 10 digit number with no spaces, dashes, dots, with area code included. I know this isn't the technical "best" way to validate phone numbers but for our purposes it works. This is section of code I have to generate the field. (edited to make a more reproducible example)

```
function CreateForm() {
  var form = FormApp.create('Test');

  var tenantNum = form.addTextItem()
  .setTitle("Tenant Phone #");
  var phoneValid = FormApp.createTextValidation()
  .setHelpText("Please enter valid phone number, 10-digits, no symbols or spaces.")
  .requireTextMatchesPattern(/\d{10}/g)
  .build();
  tenantNum.setValidation(phoneValid);

  console.log(form.getPublishedUrl())
}
```

I have also tried other things like:

(No capture group or global tag, both individually)

```
.requireTextMatchesPattern(/\d{10}/)
```

Entering the regex as a string literal.

```
.requireTextMatchesPattern("\d{10}")
```

Even dumdum stuff like.

```
.requireTextMatchesPattern(/[0-9]{10}/)
```

or

```
.requireTextMatchesPattern(/\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d/)
```

Just to see if it works. I have also tried `.requireTextContainsPattern()` as well.

Whenever you enter in the form however i get this response:

> Please enter valid phone number, 10-digits, no symbols or spaces.

[image]

My only thought is that there might be some confusion with whether or not the user is entering a string vs. number and this method only works on strings. But this validation
and regex work fine when you enter it into the form creation manually so I'm completely lost. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There's no setHelpText() method in Class TextValidationBuilder

Comment: This is code I literally pulled from the Apps Script Docs.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/text-validation-builder

Comment: Oh I guess that's the same reference.  But look at the methods.  There's no setHelpText so I'd guess the person writing the example may have screwed up.

Comment: I sent them feedback to let them know about the possible error.

Comment: In any case that did not work, now it just doesn't recognize it and says "Must Match Pattern".

Comment: I didn't offer it as answer.  I was simply pointing out that there are no such methods in that class so that way that it is written is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess... Try this:

```
.requireTextMatchesPattern("\\d{10}")
```

**Update**

It works fine for me:

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
function CreateForm() {
  var form = FormApp.create('Test');

  var tenantNum = form.addTextItem()
  .setTitle("Tenant Phone #");
  var phoneValid = FormApp.createTextValidation()
  .setHelpText("Please enter valid phone number, 10-digits, no symbols or spaces.")
  .requireTextMatchesPattern("\\d{10}")
  .build();
  tenantNum.setValidation(phoneValid);

  console.log(form.getPublishedUrl())
}
```

And the "not existed" method `setHelpText()` works fine as well, as you can tell from the screenshots.

Comment: No unfortunately that didn't work. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: I'm not very fluent with google forms. If you post a reproducible fragment of your code I'd try to figure out where the error is. And perhaps not only me could do try it as well.

Comment: I edited it! Sorry, still new to this. Thanks again

Comment: The try from my answer `.requireTextMatchesPattern("\\d{10}")` works fine for me.

Comment: Lmao i'm dead right now, I definitely did try it but its possible I left the global tag in when i did your method and that messed it up. It's definitely confusing because almost everywhere else in Apps Script it follows the typical Javascript syntax for RegExes but here i guess the want the actual string. 

Thanks alot man!

Comment: And this is exactly why it's always a good idea to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Why does it work to have two slashes before the d? Is this something specific to appscript?

Comment: It has to do with JavaScript engine. In this case we need a string **"\d"**. But a single slash symbol **"\"** will be interpreted by JavaScript engine as a special symbol before the next symbol and we get the regular expression **"\d"** (any digit), not a string **"\d"**. To make the string **"\d"** we need use **"\\d"** (the double slash **"\\"** will interpreted  as a single slash **"\"**)